# How can I get the pow of a number in FTL template?

Tags: freemarker

I want to get the pow of a number in FreeMarker but I can't find any math function for this.

Example : `X / 10 ^ n => 3000 / 10 ^ 3 = 3`

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

First, in Java class, you can do like this (model is a import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap variable.):

```
import freemarker.ext.beans.BeansWrapper;

model.put("Math", BeansWrapper.getDefaultInstance().getStaticModels().get("java.lang.Math"));
```

Then, in FTL, you can use it:

```
${X / (Math.pow(10, n))}
```